# How to position fields side by side with css

Tags: css, wordpress

I use a hotel booking plugin in wordpress (theme: Divi), and the availability search bar has this current view: https://www.fenyvesivendeghaz.hu/proba-oldal/

I would like something as I attached: [image: Pict]

How can I create with css ?

Currently I have these lines:

```
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}

input[type=text] {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 40px;
    float: left;
    padding: 16px 20px;
}

select {
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    float: left;
}

.input[type=text] {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 48.8%;
}

.input[type=text] {
    margin-right: 1.4%;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use this-

```
.mphb_sc_search-form p {
    display: inline-table;
    margin-right: 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Or if you want to apply this on inputs & button within that form only(exclude "A kötelezően kitöltendő mezőket követi a") then use this-

```
.mphb_sc_search-form p:not(:first-child) {
    display: inline-table;
    margin-right: 25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

To center the form-

```
.mphb_sc_search-form {
    text-align: center;
}
```

To remove "A kötelezően kitöltendő mezőket követi a *"-

```
p.mphb-required-fields-tip {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Arif! You helped a lot! 

How can i put "A kötelezően kitöltendő mezőket követi a" under the form AND how can i delete it? 

i want this form to be displayed as a full width+aligned center,  Like here: https://themes.getmotopress.com/?theme=Oceanica#_ga=2.3391856.1121316914.1513617733-1994727348.1513617733 How can i do that?

I also want the green submit button in the same horizantal position as the fields. :)